# Search for string which has double quotes in powershell windows 8

Tags: windows, powershell, select-string

I have a file which contains below content -

```
serial_no= 1 name="abc.txt" type="Text" date="25-06-18"
serial_no= 2 name="abc.bmp" type="Bitmap" date="23-06-18"
serial_no= 3 name="abc.jpg" type="Image" date="21-06-18"
serial_no= 4 name="abc2.txt" type="Text" date="26-06-18"
serial_no= 5 name="abc.log" type="LogFile" date="19-06-18"
serial_no= 6 name="abc.exe" type="Program" date="20-06-18"
serial_no= 7 name="abc.jar" type="Java Archive" date="25-06-18"
serial_no= 8 name="abc3.txt" type="Text" date="11-06-18"
```

I want to search for **type="Text"**

I tried Select-String with many values for -pattern option, but always get error -

Command -

```
Select-String -path "path\filename.log" -pattern "type="Text""
```

Error -

```
Select-String : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Text'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Select-String -path "...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-String], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand
```

Can someone tell me how can I modify my command to search for such a string which has double quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the strings by using `'` instead of `"` on the outside:

```
Select-String -path "path\filename.log" -pattern 'type="Text"'
```

Gives you the correct output (e.g.):

```
filename.log:1:serial_no= 1 name="abc.txt" type="Text" date="25-06-18"
filename.log:4:serial_no= 4 name="abc2.txt" type="Text" date="26-06-18"
filename.log:8:serial_no= 8 name="abc3.txt" type="Text" date="11-06-18"
```

Comment: Thanks. Should have figured this out :)

Comment: @JamesBond if the answer solved the problem, please mark it as the correct answer.
Glad i could help :)

Comment: Done. Thanks for help.

Comment: Does this only work since a specific PS version? I have major version 3 on a server and it does not work there for a simple string and I can easily find the string in the file, there are no other special characters and also no newlines or something like that.

Comment: @bugybunny it should work in every PS version up to PSv3 (`Select-String` was released there, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-3.0). What exactly is your problem? You can find the string in the file but not if you try to fatch it as a pasted string in the shell? Without seeing the actual code its hard to help you. If your question exceeds this one, maybe create an own question on the topic and show an [mcve] of the problem.